# Error: "Using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'"

Tags: c++

I wrote `#include <iostream>` before `using namespace std;`, but it didn't help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool argument (double & x);
double analytical_formula (double x);
double rekurentno (double x, int & N_adds);
```

Comment: can't reproduce. What compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: Previously reported without solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876889/error-using-directive-refers-to-implicitly-defined-namespace-std. "I get the error in CLion but in VS code everything works." Are you using CLion as well?

Comment: @ThomasSablik The code here includes standard headers before the `using` declaration, whereas your code and the linked question do not.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, I know but maybe the headers are somehow optimized out because they are not used or it's not a correct [mcve]